# Multiple GADBannerView in UiCollectionView is not scrolling smoothly in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, gadbannerview

I have a collection view in my project with lots of data coming from a web service, with GADBAnnerView(AdMob) on every 4th position. Ads are showing but it doesn't scroll smoothly.

```
- (void)preloadNextGoogleBannerAd {
if (!adMobBannersToLoad.count) {
    return;
}
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    GADBannerView *adView = adMobBannersToLoad.firstObject;
    [adMobBannersToLoad removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
       [adView loadRequest:request];
    });
});
```

And in cellForItemAtIndexPath of CollectionView

```
for (UIView *subview in reusableAdCell.contentView.subviews) {
  [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

GADBannerView *adView = _tableViewItems[indexPath.row];
[reusableAdCell.contentView addSubview:adView];
adView.center = reusableAdCell.contentView.center;

return reusableAdCell;
```

Can someone help me for this issue?

Comment: Hi, can you add a screenshot? Do you have a 1x1, 2x2, 3x3 ? because the object if is like a list you can use a UITableView.

Comment: @Ladd.c. I can't use UITableView for my purpose actually. I am using UICollectionView which is inside UIContainerView.

Comment: Now i got my doubt like usually the UI hangs when there is timeout error or some kind  of error received from AdMob

Comment: Where is this method 'preloadNextGoogleBannerAd' called? I think the problem is with the dispatch_async called from some UICollectionView method because I had similar problems

Comment: First i call "preloadNextGoogleBannerAd" after i get data from server, then when i receive the AdView in "adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)adView" this method

Comment: @Ladd.c Even after i removed dispatch_async no use, I am doing this one after the another, so when it come to end of the list. it give an error "Request Error: The Google Ad request was unable to be fulfilled before a timeout occurred". after i get this error , UICollectionView cant scroll smoothly. Do you know how to handle this ?

Comment: @Akhil :  Is it possible display different Ads on each recurring items?

Comment: @Priya :Yes its possible.

Comment: @Akhil: Please post your answer if possible here. I am getting same Ads in each recurring items.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62485567/ios-swift-google-addmob-sdk-how-to-display-different-ads-in-recurring-items-in